# compile unmanaged DLL for 32 bits on 64-bit computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

I've got a new computer with Win7-64 on it.  I installed VS2010, and am trying to compile a C++ unmanaged DLL for a 32-bit environment.  When I look at the created DLL in Dependency Walker, I see my file is 32-bit, but all dependent DLLs are 64-bit, and the error message: Modules with different CPU types were found.

What do I need to do so that the DLL is usable, and I don't see an error in depends.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 32-bit Dependency Walker (both can be installed on the same machine).

Dependency Walker isn't smart enough to use the WOW64 directories, so 32-bit dependencies are only found when Dependency Walker is itself running inside WOW64.

Comment: Fascinating.  You're right.  But I still get error 8007007E when I try to P/Invoke a function in the DLL -- which I had hoped was because of the 64/86 mismatch.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: @Erict: Is the application loading the DLL 32-bit?

Comment: I'm an idiot.  At some time during my conversion of the project to the 64 bit environment, my output folder changed from bin\Debug to bin\x86\Debug.  I didn't notice this and the postbuild event kept copying the DLL into bin\Debug.  Everything works fine now.  Thanks!